# Dynamically allocated Array of pointers to structures

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to allocate enough space for an array of pointers to structure(City) with

```
City **ptrArray = (City **)calloc(numberOfLines, sizeof(City*));

char tempArray[100];
char* temp = tempArray;
int slength;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++)
    { //Allocates enough memory for array of length of string
        fscanf(fPtr, "%99[^:] %*c", tempArray);
        slength = strlen(temp);
        ptrArray[i] = (City*)malloc(sizeof(int)+(sizeof(char)*slength));
        strcpy(ptrArray[i]->cityName, temp);
        //fscanf(fPtr, "%d", ptrArray[i]->temperature);
    }
```

This is where I read the data from a file into the array.  The debugger(visual studio) only shows one cell in ptrArray and it seems that the data gets lost.
numberOfLines is an assigned int value.
tempArray is a temporary holding place for the strings read from the file.
temp is a pointer to tempArray.

Bonus issue: The commented out line at the bottom of the for loop breaks the code every time and I have no clue why.

edit: I added the code where I initialized temp and tempArray.
Also it is a weird call to malloc because the assignment specifies allocating exactly enough memory for the string and an int instead of having a maximum value for the string.  And here is my struct

```
typedef struct{
    int temperature;
    char cityName[100];
}City;
```

Thank you very much for you help!

Comment: In C, don't cast the results of `malloc`.

Comment: You're calling strlen(temp) before temp has any value assigned; perhaps you mean tempArray? Likewise, you call scanf expecting an int, but then you give it temp instead of the address of an int variable that scanf wants. You don't show the declarations of temp or tempVar here. Also, why the bizarre argument to the second malloc()?

Comment: The size of the structure is not always the sum of its members due to memory alignment. You are better of with `sizeof(City*)`. This is what breaks the commented line in the loop. Note that it is impossible to find all the issues with a very small snippet of a code.

Comment: @alvits I need the size of the string within the struct to change size depending on the length of the string being read.   Is there a better way I could do this?  And this is really the only code that is executing besides checking input from the user and opening the file.

Comment: You can't assume that the sum of `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(char)*strlen` will work because there will be padding to compensate for alignment within the structure. You defined `City` to have a member of `int` and `char[100]`. Stick with it. If you want dynamic character length within the structure, you must define it as such.

Comment: @alvits Could you please give me an example on how to define a dynamic character length?  I keep getting errors saying "non-constant expression as array bound".

Comment: I would suggest modifying the structure to be `int` and `char *`. This will allow dynamically allocated string. But you will have to allocate the character string for every record. In short, when you allocate memory for a `City *`, you will also need to allocate a memory for `City->cityName` which is a `char *`. `ptrArray[i] = malloc(sizeof(City *))` and `City->cityName = malloc(sizeof(char)*slength+1)` respectively.

Comment: Thank you @user3121023 and @alvits!    The temperature is now being read and I believe that all of the memory is being allocated correctly as far as the For loop goes.  The PtrArray is still only showing up as one element though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamic allocation of cityName.

```
typedef struct{
    int temperature;
    char *cityName;// pointer to char
}City;

City **ptrArray = calloc(numberOfLines, sizeof(City*));
if ( ptrArray == NULL) {
    printf ( "calloc failed\n");
    exit(1);
}

char tempArray[100];
int slength;

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++)
{
    if ( ( fscanf(fPtr, "%99[^:] %*c", tempArray)) != 1) {
        //handle problem - break or return or exit.
    }
    slength = strlen(tempArray);
    ptrArray[i] = malloc( sizeof(City));// memory for structure
    if ( ptrArray[i] == NULL) {
        printf ( "malloc failed\n");
        exit ( 1);
    }
    ptrArray[i]->cityName = malloc( 1 + slength));// memory for cityName + 1 for '\0'
    if ( ptrArray[i]->cityName == NULL) {
        printf ( "malloc failed\n");
        exit (1);
    }
    strcpy(ptrArray[i]->cityName, tempArray);
    if ( ( fscanf(fPtr, "%d", &ptrArray[i]->temperature)) != 1) {
        //handle problem break or return or exit
    }
}
```

Memory allocated should also be freed when it is no longer needed.  `numberOfLines` and `ptrArray` may have different names outside this function and the corresponding names would be used instead.

```
for ( i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
    free ( ptrArray[i]->cityName);
    free ( ptrArray[i]);
}
free ( ptrArray);
```

Comment: I am still not getting an array of pointers in ptrArray.  I am only getting one pointer to the start of the memory, no cells.   Also I have to put (City**) in front of calloc for it to compile, otherwise I get an error.

Comment: @Kris When you say you are not getting an array of pointers, how are you determining that?

Comment: "Error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'City **'" is the error I'm getting.

Comment: I was going off of my debugger how it would show an array and as it would iterate through the loop it would not show any change to anything.  I believed it to be not doing anything.   Now it seems to be working fine.   Thank you guys for your help.